# How do I use python's pop and append to create series of variable lists?

Tags: python, list, append

I'm new to python, and trying to get an output of series of variables in different orders. For instance, I want to have several lists, with things like ABC, DEF, GHI and get an output of ADG, ADH, ADI, AEG, AEH... and so forth. I'm sure this isn't as hard as I'm making it, but I'm a little lost with how I use pop and append in loops to do this.

I've been messing around with pop and append in different orders to try and create the output I want, but I don't think I quite understand how append operates. I can get an output that has the letters in the order I want, but with (please see my code for what I mean) lots of extra list items I don't want printed.

```py
first=[["A"],["B"],["C"]]
second=[["D"],["E"],["F"]]
third=[["G"],["H"],["I"]]
possible=[]

for letter1 in first: 
    possible.append(letter1) 
    for letter2 in second: 
        possible.append(letter2)
        for letter3 in third: 
            possible.append(letter3)
print(possible)
```

The output of that is:
[['A'], ['D'], ['G'], ['H'], ['I'], ['E'], ['G'], ['H'], ['I'], ['F'], ['G'], ['H'], ['I'], ['B'], ['D'], ['G'], ['H'], ['I'], ['E'], ['G'], ['H'], ['I'], ['F'], ['G'], ['H'], ['I'], ['C'], ['D'], ['G'], ['H'], ['I'], ['E'], ['G'], ['H'], ['I'], ['F'], ['G'], ['H'], ['I']]

What I would like is:
ADG, ADH, ADI, AEG, AEH, AEI, AFG, AFH, AFI, BDG...

I would really appreciate any help you can bring. Thanks so much for taking the time to read this!

Comment: Where are you popping? Why are your lists nested like that?

Comment: Look at `list('ABC')` vs `list(map(list, 'ABC'))`, which is what you have.

Comment: The question is about [permutations] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) and/or [combinations] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). Please consider first read and understand them before trying to do anything in python. Unless you are just trying to learn how to use `list.pop()` (https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: @iliasiliadis that's a very useful comment, but you should clean up your markdown. remove the spaces between the `[permutations]` and the `(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)` and similar for combinations and etc

Comment: There is a much simpler solution for the *actual problem*, as @AdamSmith shows you. But let's think about this logically, so you understand how to apply the logic: "What I would like is: ADG, ADH, ADI, AEG, AEH, AEI, AFG, AFH, AFI, BDG" - therefore, you need to produce e.g. the `'ADG'` string *before* you `.append` it to the list. Hint: Inside the innermost loop, the very first time around, you have `letter1` available and equal to `'A'`, `letter2` similarly equal to `'D'` and `letter3` equal to `'G'`. How can you produce the string `'ADG'` from these?

Answer (score 1):

No reason to use `pop` here. `pop` is actually destructive since after `['a', 'b', 'c'].pop()`, `'c'` is no longer available to populate any other lists.

What you should do instead is simply iterate over each list. I'm actually going to make these strings for now, just because it removes some complexity and it's not clear what your actual output should be if they're not, but it's fairly easy to reason upwards about this.

```py
as, bs, cs = 'abc', 'def', 'ghi'

possible = []

for a in as:
    for b in bs:
        for c in cs:
            possible.append([a, b, c])

assert possible == [['a', 'd', 'g'], ['a', 'd', 'h'], ['a', 'd', 'i'], ['a', 'e', 'g'], ...]
```

Also worth noting that this sort of "chain" for loop is a common enough application that it is implemented in the standard library as `itertools.product`.

```py
import itertools
# assume as, bs, cs, and possible are defined as above

for a, b, c in itertools.product(as, bs, cs):
    possible.append([a, b, c])
```

Indeed this sort of "iterate over a collection and build a new list from it" is common enough that list comprehensions are a concept not just in Python but many other languages too. In Python the syntax looks like:

```py
import itertools
# as, bs, and cs are defined as above

possible = [[a, b, c] for a, b, c in itertools.product(as, bs, cs)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the list to have only 1 index. The one in the code given by you has 2 indices since it is like a list in a list.

```
first=["A","B","C"]
second=["D","E","F"]
third=["G","H","I"]


for letter1 in first:
    word = ""
    word += letter1
    for letter2 in second: 
        word = word[:1] + letter2
        for letter3 in third: 
            word = word[:2] + letter3 
            print(word)
```